# Why is my loop adding an additional key value pair at the end of my YAML file?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have two separate YAML files that I'm parsing through using `ruamel.yaml`.

File_one:

```
---
value: 600
another_value: 330
main_config::config::config:
  username:
    password: 'ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD'
    name: 'John Doe'
    role: 'admin'
    expiration: '2055-01-01'
    email: 'username@email.com'
```

and File_two:

```
---
main_config::config::config:
  username:
    password: 'ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD'
    name: 'John Doe'
    role: 'admin'
    expiration: '2055-01-01'
    email: 'username@email.com'
another_config::config:
  setting1:
    setting2:
      setting3:
        setting4: false
```

I'm using raumel to parse through the files and update the expiration dates, while preserving the entire file. However it seems to work in File_one but NOT file_two.

File_two will not only update the expiration date, but add an additional expiration date to the end of the file as well, like so:

```
---
main_config::config::config:
  username:
    password: 'ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD'
    name: 'John Doe'
    role: 'admin'
    expiration: '2055-01-01'
    email: 'username@email.com'
another_config::config:
  setting1:
    setting2:
      setting3:
        setting4: false
    expiration: '2055-01-01'
```

The snippet of code I am using is:

```
with open(f"./path/to/file.yaml", 'r') as f:
    file = yaml.load(f)

    for k, v in file.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for x, y in v.items():
                if isinstance(y, dict):
                    y['expiration'] = DATE
    # Write new expiration date to file in CM:
    with open(f"./path/to/file.yaml", "w") as edit_file:
        yaml.dump(file, edit_file)
```

Why the output is different for both files using the same code?

Comment: Your code seems to add an `expiration` attribute whenever it's processing a `dict` at that level, so it will add one to `setting1` as well. Under what condition exactly do you want to add `expiration`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think more carefully about the logic. What is the *rule that tells you* where the `expiration` data should be written? Should it ever be added, or only modified where it already exists?

Comment: @Grismar The entire code takes a set of arguments, and based on that argument, if the username already exists and I only need to change the expiration date, then change the expiration date based on the user's input (yes, no). Otherwise, I'll add an entire username, role, email expiration date, etc setting to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `File_one` has only one key at the root level that has a dict as value and the expiration date gets updated in that. Your `File_two` has two keys at the root level that have a dict as value, and they both get updated. Because the input is different and triggers the "update expiration" piece of code twice in the second YAML example, the output is different. That is true in general: if the behaviour of code is dependend on the data processed, the output can differ for different input, although the code is the same.

You can add an extra test to see if `expiration` is a key in the dict before you update it (i.e. you'll never add it if it is not already there:

```
            if isinstance(y, dict) and 'expiration' in y:
```

, or you can exit if you always want to add the expiration key to the first dict found:

```
            if isinstance(y, dict):
                y['expiration'] = DATE
                break
```

Problematic is that your code writes to an open file while it is still being read. You could move your last two lines outside of the initial `with` statement, but I recommend using `pathlib.Path` that will properly open the files as binaries (necessary to dump as UTF-8):

```py
from pathlib import Path
yaml_file = Path('./path/to.file.yaml')
data = yaml.load(yaml_file)

for k, v in file.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for x, y in v.items():
            if isinstance(y, dict):
                y['expiration'] = DATE
                break

# Write new expiration date to file in CM:
yaml.dump(file, yaml_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try this,

```py
if isinstance(y, dict) and 'expiration' in y:
    y['expiration'] = DATE
```

So,  your code would look like

```py
with open(f"./path/to/file.yaml", 'r') as f:
    file = yaml.load(f)

    for k, v in file.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for x, y in v.items():
                if isinstance(y, dict) and 'expiration' in y:
                    y['expiration'] = DATE
    # Write new expiration date to file in CM:
    with open(f"./path/to/file.yaml", "w") as edit_file:
        yaml.dump(file, edit_file)
```